# Encrypted semantic search

Tags: cryptography, machine-learning, searchable-encryption

I want to implement semantic search but in an encrypted fashion.

For storing passwords, we store Enc(password) in a database, and when a user logs in, we check if Enc(query) == entry in the database.

But for semantic search, is it possible to do the following: A user has a bunch of d-dimensional text embeddings (say from an OpenAI model) e_1 e_2 ... e_n. We then store Enc(e_1) ... Enc(e_n) in a database.

Then, the user searches for some query q. With normal semantic search, we would compare the distance between each e_i and q and choose the closest distance matches. But is there a scheme  such that the dist(e_i, q) is approximately equal to dist(Enc(e_i), Enc(q))? This would allow us to do semantic search without an attacker learning about the contents of each e_i and q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it *possible*? Yes, [distance-preserving encryption](https://dbis.ipd.kit.edu/download/SSDBM-Tex-Author-Version.pdf) is theoretically possible.

But without delving too deep into the mathematics of the thing, this also weakens security on the encryption unless you can guarantee somehow that you can't e.g. compose e_i from two smaller e_j and e_k, or that estimate about the distance between (e_j + e_k) and (x) is not related to the distance between e_j and x; because if it *is*, you can treat the distance estimator as an oracle function and break the encryption piecemeal using repeated known-text attacks.

Several approaches to prevent attacking DPE are presented [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/1666.pdf), in a scenario that seems to me to closely match yours.